# Userlocation bubble annotation changing to custom annotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

I am adding a custom annotation along with the user's current location default bubble annotation but the user location annotation is changing to the other custom location after sometime when not in focus on mapview.

My viewForAnnotation method is :

```
 -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
 {

     NSString* annotationidentifier = @"customview";
     CustomAnnotationView *customannotationview = (CustomAnnotationView*) [self.mapview dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationidentifier];

     if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
     {
         customannotationview = [[CustomAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotationWithImage:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationidentifier annotationviewimage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"location pin28.png"]];

         customannotationview.canShowCallout = YES;
         return customannotationview;


     }

     else if(![annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]] && annotation != _mapview.userLocation && (annotation.coordinate.latitude != _locationmanager.location.coordinate.latitude && annotation.coordinate.longitude != _locationmanager.location.coordinate.longitude))
     {
         customannotationview = [[CustomAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotationWithImage:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationidentifier annotationviewimage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]];

         return customannotationview;


     }
     return customannotationview;

 }
```

I have put conditions in the custom annotation but still after some time if userlocation is out of focus for somtime it changes to image1.png

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is the fact that both your user annotation and location annotation use the same identifier. What happens is, when you scroll the map around, your annotations get reused (the same way a table would reuse cells), and eventually, one of your location annotations is used for your user annotation.

Try giving the annotations different identifiers, or, if you have a small number of locations, remove the reuse code, that should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for this , but I solved it by returning nil in place of customannotationview in the userlocation annotation.